# Nestjs throws NotFoundException instead of MethodNotAllowedException

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, nestjs

I have developed a Rest API using NestJS. I need to return a customized error response when the user invokes an endpoint using the wrong HTTP method.

For example, I have an endpoint GET /cats I want to return a Method Not Allowed response when the user invokes it using POST or PUT but nestjs throws `NotFoundException` instead of `MethodNotAllowedException`.

PS: in the exception filter I handle the `NotFoundException` for routes that don't exist but I want to handle `MethodNotAllowedException` for routes called with wrong method.

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
  @Get()
  findAll(): string {
    return 'This action returns all cats';
  }
}
```

Comment: There is an issue about that in  the nestjs repository on github https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2546  Ie, it's the default behaviour of the underlying libraries. If you really need to return a 405 status, you could use `@All()` instead of `@Get()` and check the method inside the handler

Answer (score 0):

Due to the complexity of my controllers, I chose not to use the @All decorator solution to check the method inside the handler. Instead, I developed a route filter middleware.

```
import { Injectable, MethodNotAllowedException, NestMiddleware, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { NextFunction, Response,Request } from 'express';
import * as pathToRegexp from 'path-to-regexp';

@Injectable()
export class RouteFilterMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  private routes = [
    { path: '/status', allowedMethods: ['GET'] },
    { path: '/cats/:id', allowedMethods: ['GET','POST'] },
  ];

  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {}

  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const apiPrefix = this.configService.get('app.apiPrefix');
    const endpoint = req.url.replace(`/${apiPrefix}`, '');

    const matchingRoute = this.routes.find((route) => {
      const regex = pathToRegexp(route.path);
      return regex.test(endpoint);
    });

    if (!matchingRoute) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }

    if (matchingRoute.allowedMethods.includes(req.method)) {
      next();
    } 
      throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
  }
}
```